# sass-maven-plugin - Failed to execute SASS ruby script

Tags: ruby, eclipse, maven, sass

I am using Maven, Eclipse and Sass to develop a webapp. To bind everything together, I am using the [sass-maven-plugin](https://github.com/Jasig/sass-maven-plugin) and [m2e jasig sass connector](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2e-jasig-sass-connector/). While processing my .scss files from the command line, with maven goal sass:update-stylesheets, everything is fine. Unfortunately, when run in Eclipse, it doesn't work. I keep getting the following error :

```
Failed to execute SASS ruby script: ...
```

followed by a Ruby script. I looked at the sass-maven-plugin code, and found this java code:

```
 try {
CompilerCallback compilerCallback = new CompilerCallback(log);
jruby.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE).put("compiler_callback", compilerCallback);
jruby.eval(sassScript);
if (failOnError && compilerCallback.hadError()) {
throw new MojoFailureException("SASS compilation encountered errors (see above for details).");
}
}
catch (final ScriptException e) {
throw new MojoExecutionException("Failed to execute SASS ruby script:\n" + sassScript, e);
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know what the ScriptException e caught has to say to me. Does anyone know how I can either solve this problem or get more info on what the cause is? Thanks a lot!

Here's part of my pom.xml :

```
    ...
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jasig.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-css</id>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-stylesheets</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <useCompass>true</useCompass>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <source>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                        </source>
                        <destination>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources</destination>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
```

Also, I posted this issue both on the [connector's](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2e-jasig-sass-connector/issues/detail?id=2) and the [maven plugin's](https://github.com/Jasig/sass-maven-plugin/issues/72) pages.

EDIT :

Okay, if I actually right click on the pom.xml -> Run as -> maven build -> sass:update-stylesheets, it works too. There's only the incremental build that triggers the exception.

EDIT2 :

And if I run a mvn eclipse:eclipse from a console, same deal, works just fine

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? We have the same problem here with maven run from the command line.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remember, but there was some ping pong between the people from the connector and the plugin to figure out which one was the culprit. I think I never got the answer, and moved to rails...

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for your answer. We have solved it. It had to do with GEM_PATH environment variable being set by RVM on a Mac. Once we removed that, it worked just fine.

Comment: remove gem path by: `unset GEM_PATH`